# When I init greenplum it print [FATAL]:-Errors generated from parallel processes

Tags: database, postgresql, parallel-processing, centos, greenplum

I have 1 centos service as master and 3 centos services as slaves.
when I first set up greenplum, I used the command gpinitsystem -c initsystem_config -s sdw3 ,it show

```
20160713:12:52:45:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Initdb to be used          = /opt/greenplum/bin/initdb
20160713:12:52:45:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-GP_LIBRARY_PATH is         = /opt/greenplum/lib
20160713:12:52:45:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[WARN]:-Ulimit check               = Warnings generated, see log file <<<<<
20160713:12:52:45:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Array host connect type    = Single hostname per node
20160713:12:52:45:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Master IP address [1]      = ::1
20160713:12:52:45:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Master IP address [2]      = 192.168.0.59
20160713:12:52:45:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Master IP address [3]      = fe80::f816:3eff:feee:647f
20160713:12:52:45:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Standby Master             = sdw3
20160713:12:52:45:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Primary segment #          = 2
20160713:12:52:45:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Standby IP address         = ::1
20160713:12:52:45:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Standby IP address         = 192.168.0.56
20160713:12:52:45:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Standby IP address         = fe80::f816:3eff:fec6:c59
20160713:12:52:45:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Total Database segments    = 6
20160713:12:52:45:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Trusted shell              = /usr/bin/ssh
20160713:12:52:45:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Number segment hosts       = 3
20160713:12:52:45:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Mirror port base           = 43000
20160713:12:52:45:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Replicaton port base       = 34000
20160713:12:52:45:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Mirror replicaton port base= 44000
20160713:12:52:45:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Mirror segment #           = 2
20160713:12:52:45:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Mirroring config           = ON
20160713:12:52:45:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Mirroring type             = Group
20160713:12:52:45:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:----------------------------------------
20160713:12:52:45:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Greenplum Primary Segment Configuration
20160713:12:52:45:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:----------------------------------------
20160713:12:52:45:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-sdw1  /home/gpadmin/gpdata/gpdatap1/gpseg0    33000   2   0   34000
20160713:12:52:45:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-sdw1  /home/gpadmin/gpdata/gpdatap2/gpseg1    33001   3   1   34001
20160713:12:52:45:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-sdw2  /home/gpadmin/gpdata/gpdatap1/gpseg2    33000   4   2   34000
20160713:12:52:45:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-sdw2  /home/gpadmin/gpdata/gpdatap2/gpseg3    33001   5   3   34001
20160713:12:52:45:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-sdw3  /home/gpadmin/gpdata/gpdatap1/gpseg4    33000   6   4   34000
20160713:12:52:45:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-sdw3  /home/gpadmin/gpdata/gpdatap2/gpseg5    33001   7   5   34001
20160713:12:52:45:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:---------------------------------------
20160713:12:52:45:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Greenplum Mirror Segment Configuration
20160713:12:52:45:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:---------------------------------------
20160713:12:52:45:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-sdw2  /home/gpadmin/gpdata/gpdatam1/gpseg0    43000   8   0   44000
20160713:12:52:45:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-sdw2  /home/gpadmin/gpdata/gpdatam2/gpseg1    43001   9   1   44001
20160713:12:52:45:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-sdw3  /home/gpadmin/gpdata/gpdatam1/gpseg2    43000   10  2   44000
20160713:12:52:45:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-sdw3  /home/gpadmin/gpdata/gpdatam2/gpseg3    43001   11  3   44001
20160713:12:52:45:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-sdw1  /home/gpadmin/gpdata/gpdatam1/gpseg4    43000   12  4   44000
20160713:12:52:45:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-sdw1  /home/gpadmin/gpdata/gpdatam2/gpseg5    43001   13  5   44001
Continue with Greenplum creation Yy/Nn>
y
20160713:12:52:50:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Building the Master instance database, please wait...
20160713:12:53:19:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Starting the Master in admin mode
20160713:12:53:29:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Commencing parallel build of primary segment instances
20160713:12:53:29:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Spawning parallel processes    batch [1], please wait...
......
20160713:12:53:30:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Waiting for parallel processes batch [1], please wait...
.
20160713:12:53:31:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:------------------------------------------------
20160713:12:53:31:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Parallel process exit status
20160713:12:53:31:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:------------------------------------------------
20160713:12:53:31:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Total processes marked as completed           = 0
20160713:12:53:31:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Total processes marked as killed              = 0
20160713:12:53:31:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[WARN]:-Total processes marked as failed              = 6 <<<<<
20160713:12:53:31:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:------------------------------------------------
20160713:12:53:31:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Commencing parallel build of mirror segment instances
20160713:12:53:31:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Spawning parallel processes    batch [1], please wait...
......
20160713:12:53:31:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Waiting for parallel processes batch [1], please wait...
.
20160713:12:53:32:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:------------------------------------------------
20160713:12:53:32:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Parallel process exit status
20160713:12:53:32:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:------------------------------------------------
20160713:12:53:32:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Total processes marked as completed           = 0
20160713:12:53:32:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Total processes marked as killed              = 0
20160713:12:53:32:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[WARN]:-Total processes marked as failed              = 6 <<<<<
20160713:12:53:32:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:------------------------------------------------
20160713:12:53:33:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[FATAL]:-Errors generated from parallel processes
20160713:12:53:33:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Dumped contents of status file to the log file
20160713:12:53:33:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Building composite backout file
20160713:12:53:33:gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[FATAL]:-Failures detected, see log file /home/gpadmin/gpAdminLogs/gpinitsystem_20160713.log for more detail Script Exiting!
20160713:12:53:33:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[WARN]:-Script has left Greenplum Database in an incomplete state
```

This is part of log

```
20160713:12:52:32:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function CREATE_QE_ARRAY
20160713:12:52:32:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Building primary segment instance array, please wait...
20160713:12:52:32:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function POSTGRES_PORT_CHK
20160713:12:52:32:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function GET_PG_PID_ACTIVE
20160713:12:52:32:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function PING_HOST
20160713:12:52:32:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-sdw1 contact established
20160713:12:52:32:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function PING_HOST
20160713:12:52:32:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-No socket connection or lock file /tmp/.s.PGSQL.33000.lock found for port=33000
20160713:12:52:32:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function GET_PG_PID_ACTIVE
20160713:12:52:32:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function POSTGRES_PORT_CHK
20160713:12:52:32:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function POSTGRES_PORT_CHK
20160713:12:52:32:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function GET_PG_PID_ACTIVE
20160713:12:52:32:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function PING_HOST
20160713:12:52:32:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-sdw1 contact established
20160713:12:52:32:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function PING_HOST
20160713:12:52:33:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-No socket connection or lock file /tmp/.s.PGSQL.33001.lock found for port=33001
20160713:12:52:33:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function GET_PG_PID_ACTIVE
20160713:12:52:33:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function POSTGRES_PORT_CHK
20160713:12:52:33:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function POSTGRES_PORT_CHK
20160713:12:52:33:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function GET_PG_PID_ACTIVE
20160713:12:52:33:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function PING_HOST
20160713:12:52:33:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-sdw2 contact established
20160713:12:52:33:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function PING_HOST
20160713:12:52:33:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-No socket connection or lock file /tmp/.s.PGSQL.33000.lock found for port=33000
20160713:12:52:33:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function GET_PG_PID_ACTIVE
20160713:12:52:33:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function POSTGRES_PORT_CHK
20160713:12:52:33:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function POSTGRES_PORT_CHK
20160713:12:52:33:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function GET_PG_PID_ACTIVE
20160713:12:52:33:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function PING_HOST
20160713:12:52:33:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-sdw2 contact established
20160713:12:52:33:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function PING_HOST
20160713:12:52:33:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-No socket connection or lock file /tmp/.s.PGSQL.33001.lock found for port=33001
20160713:12:52:33:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function GET_PG_PID_ACTIVE
20160713:12:52:33:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function POSTGRES_PORT_CHK
20160713:12:52:33:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function POSTGRES_PORT_CHK
20160713:12:52:33:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function GET_PG_PID_ACTIVE
20160713:12:52:33:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function PING_HOST
20160713:12:52:33:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-sdw3 contact established
20160713:12:52:33:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function PING_HOST
20160713:12:52:34:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-No socket connection or lock file /tmp/.s.PGSQL.33000.lock found for port=33000
20160713:12:52:34:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function GET_PG_PID_ACTIVE
20160713:12:52:34:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function POSTGRES_PORT_CHK
20160713:12:52:34:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function POSTGRES_PORT_CHK
20160713:12:52:34:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function GET_PG_PID_ACTIVE
20160713:12:52:34:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function PING_HOST
20160713:12:52:34:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-sdw3 contact established
20160713:12:52:34:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function PING_HOST
20160713:12:52:34:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-No socket connection or lock file /tmp/.s.PGSQL.33001.lock found for port=33001
20160713:12:52:34:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function GET_PG_PID_ACTIVE
20160713:12:52:34:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function POSTGRES_PORT_CHK
20160713:12:52:34:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function CREATE_GROUP_MIRROR_ARRAY
20160713:12:52:34:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Building group mirror array type , please wait...
20160713:12:52:34:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function POSTGRES_PORT_CHK
20160713:12:52:34:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function GET_PG_PID_ACTIVE
20160713:12:52:34:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function PING_HOST
20160713:12:52:34:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-sdw2 contact established
20160713:12:52:34:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function PING_HOST
20160713:12:52:34:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-No socket connection or lock file /tmp/.s.PGSQL.43000.lock found for port=43000
20160713:12:52:34:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function GET_PG_PID_ACTIVE
20160713:12:52:34:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function POSTGRES_PORT_CHK
20160713:12:52:34:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function POSTGRES_PORT_CHK
20160713:12:52:34:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function GET_PG_PID_ACTIVE
20160713:12:52:34:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function PING_HOST
20160713:12:52:34:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-sdw2 contact established
20160713:12:52:34:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function PING_HOST
20160713:12:52:35:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-No socket connection or lock file /tmp/.s.PGSQL.43001.lock found for port=43001
20160713:12:52:35:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function GET_PG_PID_ACTIVE
20160713:12:52:35:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function POSTGRES_PORT_CHK
20160713:12:52:35:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function POSTGRES_PORT_CHK
20160713:12:52:35:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function GET_PG_PID_ACTIVE
20160713:12:52:35:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function PING_HOST
20160713:12:52:35:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-sdw3 contact established
20160713:12:52:35:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function PING_HOST
20160713:12:52:35:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-No socket connection or lock file /tmp/.s.PGSQL.43000.lock found for port=43000
20160713:12:52:35:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function GET_PG_PID_ACTIVE
20160713:12:52:35:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function POSTGRES_PORT_CHK
20160713:12:52:35:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function POSTGRES_PORT_CHK
20160713:12:52:35:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function GET_PG_PID_ACTIVE
20160713:12:52:35:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function PING_HOST
20160713:12:52:35:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-sdw3 contact established
20160713:12:52:35:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function PING_HOST
20160713:12:52:35:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-No socket connection or lock file /tmp/.s.PGSQL.43001.lock found for port=43001
20160713:12:52:35:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function GET_PG_PID_ACTIVE
20160713:12:52:35:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function POSTGRES_PORT_CHK
20160713:12:52:35:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function POSTGRES_PORT_CHK
20160713:12:52:35:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function GET_PG_PID_ACTIVE
20160713:12:52:35:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function PING_HOST
20160713:12:52:35:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-sdw1 contact established
20160713:12:52:35:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function PING_HOST
20160713:12:52:36:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-No socket connection or lock file /tmp/.s.PGSQL.43000.lock found for port=43000
20160713:12:52:36:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function GET_PG_PID_ACTIVE
20160713:12:52:36:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function POSTGRES_PORT_CHK
20160713:12:52:36:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function POSTGRES_PORT_CHK
20160713:12:52:36:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function GET_PG_PID_ACTIVE
20160713:12:52:36:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function PING_HOST
20160713:12:52:36:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-sdw1 contact established
20160713:12:52:36:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function PING_HOST
20160713:12:52:36:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-No socket connection or lock file /tmp/.s.PGSQL.43001.lock found for port=43001
20160713:12:52:36:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function GET_PG_PID_ACTIVE
20160713:12:52:36:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function POSTGRES_PORT_CHK
20160713:12:52:36:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function CREATE_GROUP_MIRROR_ARRAY
20160713:12:52:36:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function CREATE_QE_ARRAY
20160713:12:52:36:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function CHK_QES
20160713:12:52:36:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Checking Master host
20160713:12:52:36:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function CHK_DIR
20160713:12:52:36:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function CHK_DIR
20160713:12:52:36:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function GET_PG_PID_ACTIVE
20160713:12:52:36:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-No socket connection or lock file in /tmp found for port=2345

...

20160713:12:53:30:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function PARALLEL_WAIT
20160713:12:53:30:009290 gpcreateseg.sh:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO][1]:-Processing segment sdw2
20160713:12:53:30:024605 gpinitsystem:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Waiting for parallel processes batch [1], please wait...
20160713:12:53:30:009418 gpcreateseg.sh:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO][2]:-Start Function PROCESS_QE
The program "postgres" is needed by initdb but was either not found in the same directory as "/opt/greenplum/bin/initdb" or failed unexpectedly.
Check your installation; "postgres -V" may have more information.
20160713:12:53:30:009418 gpcreateseg.sh:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO][2]:-Processing segment sdw3
20160713:12:53:30:009564 gpcreateseg.sh:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO][3]:-Start Main
The program "postgres" is needed by initdb but was either not found in the same directory as "/opt/greenplum/bin/initdb" or failed unexpectedly.
Check your installation; "postgres -V" may have more information.
20160713:12:53:30:009564 gpcreateseg.sh:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO][3]:-Command line options passed to utility = ::1~192.168.0.59~fe80::f816:3eff:feee:647f ::1~192.168.0.56~fe80::f816:3eff:fec6:c59
20160713:12:53:30:009754 gpcreateseg.sh:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO][4]:-Start Main
20160713:12:53:30:009754 gpcreateseg.sh:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO][4]:-Command line options passed to utility = ::1~192.168.0.59~fe80::f816:3eff:feee:647f ::1~192.168.0.56~fe80::f816:3eff:fec6:c59
20160713:12:53:30:009564 gpcreateseg.sh:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO][3]:-Start Function PROCESS_QE
20160713:12:53:30:010017 gpcreateseg.sh:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO][5]:-Start Main
20160713:12:53:30:009564 gpcreateseg.sh:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO][3]:-Processing segment sdw1
20160713:12:53:30:009754 gpcreateseg.sh:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO][4]:-Start Function PROCESS_QE
The program "postgres" is needed by initdb but was either not found in the same directory as "/opt/greenplum/bin/initdb" or failed unexpectedly.
Check your installation; "postgres -V" may have more information.
20160713:12:53:30:010017 gpcreateseg.sh:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO][5]:-Command line options passed to utility = ::1~192.168.0.59~fe80::f816:3eff:feee:647f ::1~192.168.0.56~fe80::f816:3eff:fec6:c59
20160713:12:53:30:009754 gpcreateseg.sh:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO][4]:-Processing segment sdw2
cat: /home/gpadmin/gpdata/gpdatap1/gpseg2.initdb: No such file or directory
20160713:12:53:30:010017 gpcreateseg.sh:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO][5]:-Start Function PROCESS_QE
cat: /home/gpadmin/gpdata/gpdatap1/gpseg0.initdb: No such file or directory
20160713:12:53:30:010017 gpcreateseg.sh:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO][5]:-Processing segment sdw3
The program "postgres" is needed by initdb but was either not found in the same directory as "/opt/greenplum/bin/initdb" or failed unexpectedly.
Check your installation; "postgres -V" may have more information.
cat: /home/gpadmin/gpdata/gpdatap1/gpseg4.initdb: No such file or directory
The program "postgres" is needed by initdb but was either not found in the same directory as "/opt/greenplum/bin/initdb" or failed unexpectedly.
Check your installation; "postgres -V" may have more information.
20160713:12:53:30:009290 gpcreateseg.sh:mdw:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function BACKOUT_COMMAND
The program "postgres" is needed by initdb but was either not found in the same directory as "/opt/greenplum/bin/initdb" or failed unexpectedly.
```

And this is my initgp_config

```
# Configuration file needed by the gpinitsystem
#
# ################################################

 ARRAY_NAME="Greenplum"

 SEG_PREFIX=gpseg

 PORT_BASE=33000
 declare -a DATA_DIRECTORY=(/home/gpadmin/gpdata/gpdatap1 /home/gpadmin/gpdata/gpdatap2)

 MASTER_HOSTNAME=mdw
 MASTER_DIRECTORY=/home/gpadmin/gpdata/gpmaster
 MASTER_PORT=2345
 TRUSTED_SHELL=/usr/bin/ssh
 CHECK_POINT_SEGMENTS=8
 ENCODING=UNICODE
 MIRROR_PORT_BASE=43000
 REPLICATION_PORT_BASE=34000
 MIRROR_REPLICATION_PORT_BASE=44000 
 declare -a MIRROR_DATA_DIRECTORY=(/home/gpadmin/gpdata/gpdatam1 /home/gpadmin/gpdata/gpdatam2)

MACHINE_LIST_FILE=/home/gpadmin/conf/seg_hosts
```

I tried a lot of times, and fixed some small bugs. But it also can't work. Please help me, thank you.

Comment: Did you forget to run gpseginstall?   It doesn't look like the segment hosts have the binaries installed.

Comment: Agreed - I think the path and/or binaries were never installed.  Check the installation docs here for how to run gpseginstall:  http://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/4380/prep_os-install-hosts.html#topic8

Answer (score 0):

try add `id_rsa.pub` to `authorized_keys`:

```
ie ssh-keygen 
then cp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub authorized_keys
```

taken from [here  (line 1~3)](https://github.com/greenplum-db/gpdb/blob/master/README.debian/).